# How common is the use of 'although' as a preposition rather than a conjunction?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis

Conceding a point can be expressed by means of

> – an adverb (however, nevertheless, etc);
>
> – a preposition + the point in noun form (despite this, in spite of this, despite the fact that, etc);
>
> – a conjunction + the point in the form of a clause (although this is the case, while this is the case, etc).

In Cambridge's *First Certificate Trainer, Six Practice Tests*, I found the following (p. 87, key p. 208) in a multiple choice exercise about a text entitled 'Fingernails growing faster':

> […] the human fingernail now grows about 3.5 mm a month, compared with just 3 mm seven decades ago. Toenail growth, [gap: A although; B despite; C however; D nevertheless] only about 2 mm per month, was also up on the figure obtained in a similar survey done 70 years ago.

And the answer the key gives is 'A although'. So here, 'although' is used as a kind of preposition! How common is that?

Comment: Well, it is certainly idiomatic in that and related senses.

Comment: Not even the most ardent preposition-lumper would call this an example.

Comment: **Although** is a subordinating conjunction introducing a concession clause there.

Comment: With my glasses needing a new prescription, and following as it does the word **ardent**, that word did not enter my brain as **lumper** at first.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: how do you distinguish between a word that can only be a preposition, as is 'without' in 'without waiting for an answer', and 'before' in 'before leaving' / 'before he left', where it can be either? or both?!

Comment: I've eventually found a relevant example in an authoritative work. [Collins Spanish Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/though) has: **though** A. CONJ  ... 
_though small, it's good_. It obviously treats this as an example of SUB + be deletion, and considers that sufficient to claim 'conjunction' as remaining the appropriate POS for 'though' in such deleted forms. @Professor Lawler would doubtless say 'What does giving it a label add to the argument, except heat?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That almost makes 'though' seem to fill the role of a coordinating conjunction, as in "small but good", aside from the fact that you still can't change the order to "But good, it is small." Still, you could probably theoretically replace every word joined by any coordinating conjunction with a clause, e.g. "The frog is fast, and the frog is slippery." How about "The long road that leads to your door will never disappear, and the winding road that leads to your door will never disappear."

Comment: @Chuckk Hubbard  If you look up 'FANBOYS' here, you will find an article debunking 'the myth of FANBOYS'. In particular, as CGEL spells out, they do not all behave the same way distributionally.  However, joining two independent clauses with different subjects and predicates with say 'and' and expecting to be able to delete isn't on. 'John keeps cows; Jill grows maize.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You have mentioned this FANBOYS debunking enough times that I've managed to figure it out! I didn't mean to say anything about FANBOYS. I only find the idea kind of interesting of always writing out full clauses between all conjunctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that it is a case of leaving out part of a sentence or clause, as in certain relative clauses:

> Albert Einstein, who is the most famous physicist of the XXth century, was born in Ulm.

can be reduced to

> Albert Einstein, the most famous physicist of the XXth century, was born in Ulm.

leaving out 'who was'. Similarly,

> Toenail growth, although it was only about 2mm per month, was also up on the figure obtained in a similar survey done 70 years ago.

can be reduced to

> Toenail growth, although only about 2 mm per month, was also up on the figure obtained in a similar survey done 70 years ago.

leaving out 'it was'.

The absence of a subject and a verb make 'although' seem to be a preposition here but it is definitely not. Another case of sentence simplification which complicates the task of whoever wants to understand and learn the language… !

Comment: Right, though one might also say that the long form could have been "Toenail growth, although being only about 2mm per month, ...". Both have different grammatical structure, but mean the same thing here.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. (But note that whiz-deletion is not identical to this example.)

Comment: @ user21820 It's probably correct to consider this as a two-stage deletion:   "Toenail growth, although {[it is] being} only about 2mm per month, ...".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: and why not? Is it because the deleted verb would be something like 'amounted to' rather than just 'was'? (I had never heard of 'whiz-deletion', thanks)

Comment: Deletions are best (and usually) restricted to reasonably readily recoverable elements; with verbs, repeats or  _be_.

Comment: That 'being' is definitely not functioning as a gerund. You can easily replace that 'although' with 'while', and in fact that is probably more common. With 'while' there, it is clearly elision of 'it was'.